# JQuery Mobile: pull data from an external site

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm playing with jQuery Mobile to pull some data from an external website.

Looking for an AJAX solution and I understood that it is not possible to use AJAX for pull data from an external domain due to the 'same origin policy'. Is my understanding correct? Any possible hack?

My mobile application has not its own domain since it is saved on my tablet as local app. Thanks for any useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

Native apps don't use the `same origin policy` since they don't have a domain in which they operate.

If you're talking about a website then you can use jQuery's AJAX but you need to use JSONP:

```
$.ajax('http://some-server.com/', {
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success  : function (data) {
        //do work with your `data` now
    }
});
```

This is from the `$.ajax()` docs:

> Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy
>   restrictions.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you! My mobile application should work as a native app since it does not have a domain. Simply need to format in a better way the messy content from a public transportation website for my own use. JSONP requires collaboration from the original website, if well understood and this is not the case. What do you mean with "Script requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions" ?